# Set of Permutations $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_N \}$ such that knowing $s_i(k)$ and $s_i(k + e \bmod L)$, $1 \leq e \leq D$ identifies $s_i ~ \forall k, e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, coding-theory

Let $S$ be a set containing some permutations of the alphabet $\{0, 1, \ldots, L-1\}$.
Now someone randomly draws one permutation $s_i$ from $S$, randomly chooses $k \in \{ 0, 1, \ldots, L - 1 \}$, $e \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, D \}$ (where $D < L$) and provides me with the elements $r_1 = s_i(k)$ and $r_2 = s_i(k + e \bmod L)$. I only get to know these two elements and get to know which is which, I get to see neither $k$ nor $e$.
Based on $r_1$ and $r_2$ I want to be able to **uniquely identify** which permutation $s_i$ they come from.

*How do I find a set $S$ such that $N = |S|$ is large for given $D$ and given $L$?*

**Trivial example: Ascending and Descending Sequence**
Let $L = 11$ and $D = 5$. Then $S = \{ (0, 1, \ldots, 9, 10), (10, 9, \ldots, 1, 0) \}$ (permutations written in one-line notation, think of them as sequences) is one solution with the largest possible $|S|$, namely $|S| = 2$. For instance, if I get $r_1 = 5$ and $r_2 = 3$, I know that $r_1$ and $r_2$ were drawn from the descending sequence. If it were $r_1 = 10$ and $r_2 = 0$, then it would have had to be the ascending sequence that was chosen.

For $L = 11$ and smaller $D$, it should be possible to find larger sets though.

Any hints are appreciated, especially links to possibly existing research into this question!

Comment: This may be a difficult question in general. The obvious upper bound seems to be $|S|\le\lfloor L/D\rfloor$, but I doubt that can always be achieved. At least with $L=11$, $D=3$ I couldn't find a family of three sequences (did not search very hard, but hard enough to say I'm not optimistic). On the other hand with $L=11, D=2$ we have five modular arithmetic progressions with increments $1,3,4,5,9$ that work (A stands for 10): 0123456789A, 0369147A258, 04815926A37, 05A49382716 and 097531A8642.

Comment: The search was basically to check that arithmetic progressions won't produce three sequences with parameters $L=11,D=3$. Also, it seemed to be impossible to add a third sequence to a pair of arithmetic progressions, but I didn't check all the pairs.

Comment: Mind you, $\{1,3,4,5,9\}$ is the subgroup of quadratic residues modulo $11$ and $2$ is quadratic non-residue. This generalizes to the obvious $D=2$ construction with $L$ a prime $\equiv\pm3\pmod8$ of size $|S|=(L-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you, Jyrki! This confirms my suspection that restricting the search for possible solutions to modular arithmetic progressions is a reasonable idea.

Comment: For me it's more like that I don't cherish the prospect of checking sequences that are not arithmetic progressions. The point is, of course, that we can concentrate on the difference $r_2-r_2$ modulo $L$ as a basis for identifying which sequence the data came from.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any existing research out there on this topic? The only thing I happened to come across is some research around Torleiv Kløve's [Systematic, Single Limited Magnitude Error Correcting Codes for Flash Memories](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5895071), but the application in that paper only requires searching for a good increment set (not complete sequences $s_i$). However, in my case, I'd first like to show (or disproof by counterexample) that modular arithmetic progressions are good solutions.

Comment: [Asymmetric Single Magnitude Four Error Correcting Codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01148) is also somewhat relevant to this topic. Again, the reasoning of how they end up with the same kind of set we can use as "increment set" here is completely different, but the sets named $T_d$ in Table 1 and Table 2 are good increment sets for modular arithmetic progressions for what would be $L = 2p$ and D = 4 in this notation here.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of work done on related problems. I do know that Kløve is competent :-)

Comment: This is way beyond my skill :) but just wanna point out that IMHO random choosing has nothing to do with this.  You seem to want to identify $s_i$ for any choice of $s_i, k, e$, i.e. the choices can be "adversarial" and there is no need for randomness.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question: We published [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00301) some time ago, which provides one particular construction of such permutations (but only for specific L, D).